# I accidentally 'removed' someone from a private Facebook event. How do undo this action to allow them access again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I'm hosting a private Facebook event, and one my guests RSVP'd as No. They later changed their mind and couldn't figure out how to change their RSVP. I decided to go into the event and see if I could change it myself. I couldn't figure it out, and ended up trying 'remove' to see if that would allow me to resend the invite.

Instead, it seems to have blocked/banned my friend's account from the event altogether, and I cannot find any way to undo that action or restore someone who's been removed. I cannot reinvite them (it's greyed out), and they don't appear on any of the guest lists or in any menus I can find.

Facebook's documentation seems to point to it being irreversible if you remove yourself from an event, but I cannot find a way to undo/reverse my own action as the host/owner of the event. Is there any hope of restoring their access so they can see the event?